# Async processing using xhr without waiting for a response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery form plugin to make ajax calls and upload files via ajax as we need to support IE8 which doesn't support ajax level 2

since the server takes some time to process the file, i am thinking of doing it asynchronously.

i am wondering is there a way to submit my form using ajax for only uploading/sending the file and not wait for a response.

i want ajax to send the file and then close the connection without waiting for a response from the server as it could take upto 12 - 15 minutes. It should simply display a message saying the file has been uploaded.

below is my code but it doesnt work by just removing the "success" parameter

```
function validate()
            {
                var file = $("#file").val();
                if(!file || file == '' || file == null)
                {
                    document.getElementById("outdata").innerHTML="Please select a file";
                    return false;
                }

                var options = {
                    target: '#outdata', //Div tag where content info will be loaded in
                    url:'lookup_process.php',
                    async:true,
                    beforeSubmit: function() {
                        $('#uploader').html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />'); //Including a preloader, it loads into the div tag with id uploader
                        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
                        $('input[type=reset]').attr('disabled', true);
                    },
                    timeout = 120000,
                    success:  function() {
                    //Here code can be included that needs to be performed if Ajax request was successful
                        $('#uploader').html('');
                        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
                        $('input[type=reset]').attr('disabled', false);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                        if(textStatus == 'timeout')
                        {     
                            $('#uploader').html('');
                            $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
                            $('input[type=reset]').attr('disabled', false);
                        }
                    }
                };
                $('#credit').ajaxSubmit(options);
                $('#uploader').html('');
                $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
                $('input[type=reset]').attr('disabled', false);
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: It does't work because your success function in option will be asynchronously call when response with success response.
And you have removed it.

Comment: Asynchronous requests, by their nature, do not wait for a response before continuing execution. If you remove the AJAX callbacks then nothing will happen once the server responds (or if there is a timeout). Can you outline the problem you're experiencing in more detail?

Comment: i was trialing out the above function before asking for help here. lets say even if i add that in again how can i achieve what i am trying to do. i want to upload the file to the server and close the connection without waiting for a response from the server as it could take 15 minutes to process the file.

Comment: @BrianS my problem is i want to be able to upload a file to my server which is then processed by the server which could take up to 15 minutes. now i don't want the user to wait for 15 minutes while the file is being processed instead just see a message saying file has been uploaded and we will get back to you via email once it finishes. everything works but my browser keeps waiting for the file to finish processing and keeps waiting for a response from server.

Comment: @user2280769 but isn't that the whole point of an AJAX request? Once the content has been delivered to the server you can go about your business. I haven't done a lot of file uploads via AJAX, is there some kind of blocking going on different from the normal AJAX process. If so you might consider forking the process on the server so you can close out the immediate connection while a separate process processes the file.

Comment: does the api you are using let you know when the Ajax readystate is changed? You can abort it at 2.

Comment: the only way i can abort is by putting down a timeout value and forcing it to timeout. but i dont think is the ideal way to do it. also when i do it that way my browser hangs for some reason. if i click the back button it keeps thinking and doesnt go back or make any request as seen in firebug and after a minute it fires a request to the previous page.

Comment: Is the reason for the 15 minute "processing" because the file is so big it takes 15 minutes to transfer, or because the server is literally doing stuff for 15 minutes since it requires some real intense CPU cycles?

Comment: @Nucleon the server is doing stuff for 15 minutes which requires more CPU cycles. the file is uploaded fairly quickly as its only 200KB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I better understand the problem, let me try another swing at it. Since the upload is quick, but the processing is slow there are a couple ways to solve it.

**Option 1:** The called PHP file doesn't actually process the file, instead it puts it in a queue, maybe a database or flat file. Then a cron job will execute every minute which checks for items in the queue, if the queue has unfinished jobs it processes it, once complete it will send a notification to the user(s). This can done through polling, websockets or by e-mail.

Pros: If these jobs really are resource intensive you may only want a finite amount running at once. Using a queue ensures only as many are processed as you desire, the next set will be handled when the workers are available.

Cons: Adds between 1s and 60s to each job (waiting for the next cron pulse), requires a cron task.

**Option 2:** Asynchronously call PHP code so that the request returns but will continue to process in the background until complete. [This page](http://davenewson.com/dev/methods-for-asynchronous-processes-in-php) has some excellent examples of how to do that. `shell_exec()` allows you to execute another PHP file but the request doesn't wait for that file to complete.

Pros: No cron job required. Fairly easy to setup.

Cons: If 10 people execute a job at once that takes 15 minutes to run will it decimate your webserver?

Which option is best will likely depend on your environment, load, and what resources you have available.

Comment: i am using jquery form plugin and that works fine for me. it lets me upload files to the server as mentioned above. i just call the function ajaxsubmit and it uploads the file in the form.

Comment: so is there a way you can suggest to address my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one of two solutions:

1. Once the file is uploaded, pass the processing off to a separate thread. That would allow the web request to return and not wait for the processing to finish.
2. Save the file to disk where some other process/thread is polling for files to process, or insert a record into a task database table that some other process is watching, or something similar.

I'm not sure how plausible each of these options is in php.

Comment: any tips on how to pass the processing off to a different thread ? or is there some way to pass the control from the php file to something else so the php file can finish its processing and return the message to the browser while the file is processing in the background.

Comment: See Nucleon's answer. Same concept as mine, but more tailored/detailed for php (not my forte). I would personally prefer my option 1 or his option 2.